# remove whitespace from postgresql jsonb value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

For column `json_attributes`, which holds the key `open_dates`, I need to update/standardize incoming date formats by stripping off whitespace around the `-` in the date range. For example, `"open_dates":['01/01 - 12/31']` should become `"open_dates":['01/01-12/31']`.

This simple (nonsensical) update works as expected:

```
UPDATE table
SET json_attributes = JSONB_SET(json_attributes, '{open_dates}', '1')
```

But I'm doing something wrong here, and I'm not sure how to make it right:

```
UPDATE table
SET json_attributes = JSONB_SET(json_attributes, '{open_dates}', (REPLACE('{open_dates}', ' ', '')))
```

Comment: You want `REPLACE(json_attributes->'open_dates'->>0, ' ', '')`. Or use `jsonb_extract_path_text`

Comment: or try this : `UPDATE table SET json_attributes = JSONB_SET(json_attributes, '{open_dates}', (REPLACE(json_attributes#>>'{open_dates}', ' ', '')))`